# SUMPRODUCT of last nth values with criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns (see screenshot)

[image: two columns]

How can i create a formula that sum the second LATEST column values with a criteria from column A?

For example i need the sum of the last 6 values (from column B) of the cells (in column A) that start with HH, so values starting from the bottom.
I know how to make a sum of all values (from column B) containing HH (from column A)

```
=SUMIF(A1:A;"HH"&"*";B1:B)
```

P.S. HH and * are separate because i'll substitute the HH with a cell

but now i need to delimit this to the last N values (let say last 3 values)

P.P.S.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS(A1:A;"exact text";ROW(A1:A)*{1;1};">="&ROW(A1:A)*{1;1})<=3)*(A1:A="exact text");B1:B)
```

This works so far ONLY if i write the exact text, not with values like HH*

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ss0_HiGTq07sK_FgpUKwRkgECpUNpG1hipkyYUVOcng/edit?usp=sharing

here you go!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try

```
=sum(index(query({row(A1:A), A1:B}, "Select Col3 where Col2 contains 'HH' order by Col1 desc limit 6")))
```

and see if that works?

Note:

*the string HH can be also be in a cell (ex. D1)

```
=sum(index(query({row(A1:A), A1:B}, "Select Col3 where Col2 contains '"&D1&"' order by Col1 desc limit 6")))
```

*6 indicates the number of values you want to sum

EDIT: For your locale you'll need to use in G1

```
=sum(index(query({row($B$1:$B) \ $B$1:$C}; "Select Col3 where Col2 contains '"&E2&"' order by Col1 desc limit 3")))
```

and fill down. See if that works?

[image]

Comment: this seems a bit confusing >_>

Comment: Different locale. I updated my answer. See if that works?

Comment: with a little tweaking it does what i was searching for :)

Comment: Could you add how you managed to solve your problem? It might be helpful to another member of the community.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work, not sure if it's any easier to understand/ less complicated than any other approach:

```
=SUM(SORTN(REGEXMATCH(B:B;E2)*C:C;3;0;ROW(B:B)*REGEXMATCH(B:B;E2);0))
```

Note the number 3 for the number of values you want from the bottom. and the reference to E2, which is "HH" as on your sample sheet.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(FILTER({IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(SORT(B2:B; ROW(B2:B); 0); 
 "^([A-Za-z]{1,3})\d"))\SORT(C2:C; ROW(B2:B); 0)}; COUNTIFS(
 REGEXEXTRACT(SORT(B2:B; ROW(B2:B); 0); "^([A-Za-z]{1,3})\d"); 
 REGEXEXTRACT(SORT(B2:B; ROW(B2:B); 0); "^([A-Za-z]{1,3})\d"); 
 ROW(H2:H43); "<="&ROW(H2:H43))<=3); 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")
```

full explanation **[here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqQOcPpnNvNinGBdkwar0bCKiziwCAlgxSnwPmMJH0g/edit#gid=2008413855)**

[image]